# como hacer bucle que recorra y muestre la información de base de datos

Tags: php

Estoy haciendo un pqueño web que me permita recoger datos y mostrarlos con una determinada maquetación. Lo que quiero es que en funcion del id seleccionado que sera clave principal me muestre la informacion de cada campo.

```
   <div class="fruta">


                    <img src="imagenes/<?php echo $datosLibro["imagen"]; ?>" />
                    <div class="nombreFruta"<h2>Precio: <?php echo $datosLibro['nombre']; ?> </h2><br></div>
                  <div class="precio"  <h3>Precio: <?php echo $datosLibro['precio']; ?> €</h3><br> </div>
                    <a class="btnComprar" href="#">Añadir a la cesta</a>

            <a href="#" title="Añadir este artículo a la cesta">AÑADIR AL CARRITO</a>
            <a class="remove" href="#" title="Eliminar este artículo">X</a>
        </div>
```

Comment: ¿Estás filtrando la consulta SQL con un `WHERE id=el-id-por-el-que-quieres-filtrar`?

Comment: Juan le faltan datos a tu pregunta para poder ayudarte: ¿usas mysqli, PDO? ¿puedes mostrar el código con el que estás consultando a la base de datos? Confirma si sólo quieres obtener una fila de resultados o puede haber varias filas de resultado.

Comment: Sí, estoy filtrando consulta por SQL, lo que quiero es crear un bucle que me recorrar y me muestre todos los datos contenidos en la tabla de phpmyadmin